# ios - Applications UI gets block for some time interval when pushing to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ipod

I am developing an iphone application. Some problem occurs when i try to navigate from one view controller to another view controller. When i try to navigate to another view controller the UI of the first view conrtoller get blocks or stucks for some interval of time. This happens on both real device as well as on simulator.

This is what i tried yet:

- Clean the app once , twice, thrice.
- Build the app again and again.

But not getting the way to implement this correctly. This was not happend for any other view controller in my application. So is there is any reason for this issue?

Any help will be appreciated. Please suggest some solution. This issue takes my much more time to implement.

This is the code i used when pushing to another view controller.

```
ChatViewController *chatView = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatViewController" bundle:nil];

chatView.albumName = albumName;
chatView.strAlbumID = albumID;
chatView.albumOwnerName = albumOwnerName;
chatView.strPicturesCount = imagesCount;
chatView.strFriendsCount = friendsCount;
chatView.albumCoverImageURL = albumCoverImageLink;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
```

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is happening in the view appear and of the other in the disappear methods. Those get executed when pushing a view controller.

Comment: Nothing special code is written in the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear method.


-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [Appdel updateStatusbarAndWindowFrame];
}


-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
}

Comment: how about viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear ?